# LINQ SUM with Inner Joins: How to get the Sum for a TimeSpan

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have been trying to re-write the following SQL Query by using LINQ, which I managed to do as below:

**SQL**

```
select 
    u.FirstName, 
    u.ExpectedWeeklyHours, 
    sum(t.TimeSpent)  -- SQL DataType is Time(7)

from dbo.Users u 
    inner join 
    dbo.Times t 
    on u.UserID = t.UserId
group by u.FirstName, 
         u.ExpectedWeeklyHours
```

**LINQ**

```
using (var data = new DAL())
{
    var result =
        (from times in data.Times
            join users in data.Users on times.UserId equals users.UserID
            select new
            {
                UserName = users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName, 
                ExpectedHours = users.ExpectedWeeklyHours, 
                WorkHours = times.TimeSpent
            } into x
            group x by new
            {
                UserName = x.UserName,
                ExpectedWorkingHours = x.ExpectedHours
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                UserName = g.Key.UserName,
                ExpectedWorkingHours = g.Key.ExpectedWorkingHours,
                TotalWorkingHours = g.Sum(i=>i.WorkHours)
            }
            ).ToList();
}
```

My problem is that the **WorkHours** is of type: TimeSpan and I am getting the following (Compile Time) errors:

- Cannot convert lambda expression to type
  'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' because it is not a
  delegate type 
  Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
  'System.Func' because some of the return types
  in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return
  type 
  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int'

If I replace the WorkHours column (property) with any other of type int, double or decimal it all works fine. It is only that th SUM function of Linq doesn't support TimeSpan!

Could you please help in this, thanking you in advance..

**Edit**

Based on suggestion made by wuzdik below, I have came to this solution of the issue, which I share to help whoever is in need:

```
 using (var data = new DAL())
{
    var result =
        (from times in data.Times
            join users in data.Users on times.UserId equals users.UserID
            select new
            {
                UserID = users.UserID,
                UserName = users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName,
                ExpectedHours = users.ExpectedWeeklyHours,
                WorkHours = times.TimeSpent
            }
            into x
            group x by new
            {
                UserId = x.UserID,
                UserName = x.UserName,
                ExpectedWorkingHours = x.ExpectedHours
            }).AsEnumerable().ToList();

    var finale = (from p in result
        select new TimeModelDashboard
        {
            UserId = p.Key.UserId,
            UserName = p.Key.UserName,
            ExpectedWorkingHours = p.Key.ExpectedWorkingHours,
            TotalWorkingHours = (decimal) p.Sum(t => t.WorkHours.TotalHours)
        }).ToList();

    return Json(finale);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new `TimeSpan` = sum of timespans ticks

```
TotalWorkingHours = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(w => w.WorkHours.Ticks));
```

because there isn not a overload of Sum accepting an `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>`, look here [IEnumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

EDIT:

try materializing query faster, so `new Timespan` will be called in Linq to objects

```
var result =
    (from times in data.Times
        join users in data.Users on times.UserId equals users.UserID
        select new
        {
            UserName = users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName, 
            ExpectedHours = users.ExpectedWeeklyHours, 
            WorkHours = times.TimeSpent
        } into x
        group x by new
        {
            UserName = x.UserName,
            ExpectedWorkingHours = x.ExpectedHours
        }
        into g
    ).AsEnumerable().Select(new {
            UserName = g.Key.UserName,
            ExpectedWorkingHours = g.Key.ExpectedWorkingHours,
            TotalWorkingHours = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(w => w.WorkHours.Ticks))
      }.ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried the above, but it didn't work. I got this error message: 
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @t_plusplus try metarializing query faster, as I suggested in EDIT

Comment: thank you your suggestion of Materialising the query faster worked, and I have put the final workout of this in the edit above. Kind regards.